# Split a PHP Generated DataPeriod list into Months and Years, in addition to dates

Tags: php, sorting, date, datetime

So I am generating an unordered list of all dates between two dates, using the code below. It works fine, but I want to print it a way that it creates nested lists for years and months and then the dates, i.e...

```
 - 2019
   - February
     - 02-01-2019
   - January
     - 01-01-2019
     - 01-02-2019
     ...
   ...
 - 2018
   ...
 - 2017
   ...
```

What can I do to easily achieve this?

```
<?    
$begin = new DateTime( '2017-03-12' );
$end = new DateTime('2019-02-15');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
$sdcheck = array();

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $sdcheck[] = "<li>".$date->format("m-d-Y")."</li>";
}

?>

<ul>
<?
$sdcheck = array_reverse($sdcheck);
echo implode($sdcheck);
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes I've made to make it 'easier'.  Rather than reverse the various levels of arrays, I've changed it so that the date period is generated in reverse.  I've also organised the interim array with levels according to the date, so it now is `[2019][April][]` so that it is already split into the years and months.

Then it is a case of using nested `foreach` loops to generate the various levels of lists...

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2018-03-16' );
$end = new DateTime();

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($end, $interval ,$end->diff($begin)->days);
$sdcheck = array();
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $sdcheck[$date->format("Y")][$date->format("F")][] = "<li>".$date->format("m-d-Y")."</li>";
}

$output = "<ul>";
foreach ( $sdcheck as $year=>$months )   {
    $output .="<li>".$year."<ul>";
    foreach ( $months as $month=>$dates )   {
        $output .="<li>".$month."<ul>";
        $output .=implode($dates)."</ul>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    $output .="</ul>";
}
$output .="</ul>";

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it would be:

```
function createList($daterange)
{
    $sdcheck = [];
    foreach($daterange as $date){   
        $sdcheck[$date->format('Y')][$date->format('F')][$date->format("m-d-Y")] = $date->format("m-d-Y");
    }

    $html = '';
    foreach ($sdcheck as $key => $element) {
        $html .= '<ul><li>' . $key;
        if (is_array($element)) {
            $html .= createList($element);
        }
        $html .= '</li></ul>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I went with the other answer, but yours is fine as well!